# Tests failing in GCC

Tags: macos, gcc

I'm starting to work with GCC. I downloaded the 4.4.2_release in Mac OSX and I'm running the tests through "make check-gcc" and many tests are failing, I thought that all tests of the test suite in a stable release should pass... so I have some questions:

- Is it normal? Or maybe I've done something wrong?
- Is there any default configuration that I can use for all the tests pass?

Thanks,

---

Adding more information requested:

- This is the command line I used:

  > make check-gcc RUNTESTFLAGS="dg.exp"
- Here is the summary of the results:

  ```
  === gcc Summary ===
  ```

  > expected passes       9265
  >
  > unexpected failures   1700
  >
  > unexpected successes 6
  >
  > expected failures     66
  >
  > unresolved testcases  45
  >
  > unsupported tests     93
- Here are some examples of the tests that are failing, from log file:

> FAIL: gcc.dg/20011008-1.c (test for excess errors) Excess errors:
>   /gcc_4_4_2_release/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/20011008-1.c:4: warning:
>   declaration does not declare anything
>
> FAIL: gcc.dg/20011130-1.c (test for excess errors) Excess errors:
>   /gcc_4_4_2_release/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/20011130-1.c:13: error: nested
>   functions are disabled, use -fnested-functions to re-enable
>
> FAIL: gcc.dg/20031223-1.c  (test for errors, line 10) FAIL:
>   gcc.dg/20031223-1.c  (test for warnings, line 10) FAIL:
>   gcc.dg/20031223-1.c  (test for errors, line 10) FAIL:
>   gcc.dg/20031223-1.c (test for excess errors) Excess errors:
>   /gcc_4_4_2_release/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/20031223-1.c:10: error:
>   expected expression before 'int'
>
> FAIL: gcc.dg/20041213-1.c (test for excess errors) Excess errors:
>   /gcc_4_4_2_release/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/20041213-1.c:5: error:
>   conflicting types for 'foo1'
>   /gcc_4_4_2_release/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/20041213-1.c:4: error:
>   previous declaration of 'foo1' was here
>   /gcc_4_4_2_release/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/20041213-1.c:8: error:
>   conflicting types for 'foo2'
>   /gcc_4_4_2_release/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/20041213-1.c:7: error:
>   previous declaration of 'foo2' was here
>   /gcc_4_4_2_release/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/20041213-1.c:11: error:
>   conflicting types for 'foo3'
>   /gcc_4_4_2_release/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/20041213-1.c:10: error:
>   previous definition of 'foo3' was here
>   /gcc_4_4_2_release/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/20041213-1.c:14: error:
>   conflicting types for 'foo4'
>   /gcc_4_4_2_release/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/20041213-1.c:13: error:
>   previous declaration of 'foo4' was here
>   /gcc_4_4_2_release/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/20041213-1.c:17: warning:
>   conflicting types for 'foo5'
>   /gcc_4_4_2_release/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/20041213-1.c:16: warning:
>   previous declaration of 'foo5' was here
>   /gcc_4_4_2_release/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/20041213-1.c:20: error:
>   conflicting types for 'foo6'
>   /gcc_4_4_2_release/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/20041213-1.c:19: error:
>   previous definition of 'foo6' was here
>   /gcc_4_4_2_release/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/20041213-1.c:23: error:
>   conflicting types for 'foo7'
>   /gcc_4_4_2_release/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/20041213-1.c:22: error:
>   previous definition of 'foo7' was here
>   /gcc_4_4_2_release/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/20041213-1.c:26: error:
>   conflicting types for 'foo8'
>   /gcc_4_4_2_release/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/20041213-1.c:25: error:
>   previous definition of 'foo8' was here
>   /gcc_4_4_2_release/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/20041213-1.c:29: warning:
>   conflicting types for 'foo9'
>   /gcc_4_4_2_release/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/20041213-1.c:28: warning:
>   previous implicit declaration of 'foo9' was here
>   /gcc_4_4_2_release/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/20041213-1.c:32: warning:
>   conflicting types for 'foo10'
>   /gcc_4_4_2_release/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/20041213-1.c:31: warning:
>   previous implicit declaration of 'foo10' was here
>
> FAIL: gcc.dg/Warray-bounds-3.c (test for excess errors) Excess errors:
>   cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Warray-bounds"
>
> FAIL: gcc.dg/binary-constants-2.c (test for excess errors) Excess
>   errors:
>   /gcc_4_4_2_release/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/binary-constants-2.c:12:5:
>   error: invalid suffix "b1101" on integer constant
>   /gcc_4_4_2_release/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/binary-constants-2.c:15:10:
>   error: invalid suffix "b1101" on integer constant
>
> FAIL: gcc.dg/boolcomplex-1.c (test for excess errors) Excess errors:
>   /gcc_4_4_2_release/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/boolcomplex-1.c:3: error:
>   initializer element is not constant
>
> FAIL: gcc.dg/builtins-30.c (test for excess errors) Excess errors:
>   /gcc_4_4_2_release/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/builtins-30.c:10: warning:
>   declaration of 'cos' shadows a built-in function
>   /gcc_4_4_2_release/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/builtins-30.c:17: warning:
>   declaration of 'sin' shadows a built-in function
>   /gcc_4_4_2_release/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/builtins-30.c:24: warning:
>   declaration of 'cosl' shadows a built-in function

Comment: This is not unexpected.  Unless a large percentage of the tests fail, there shouldn't be much reason to worry.

Comment: can you give some examples of the tests that are failing?

Comment: @devnull I would consider 1700 out of ~12000 a fairly significant percentage...

Comment: @twalberg the stats about failures were added later to the post.

Comment: I don't have the link handy, but you should be able to find test results for your platform at gcc.gnu.org